# c # using linq to group by multiple columns in a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by, multiple-columns

I have three columns in a datatable: string, DateTime, and decimal. I want to group by the string and decimal column, and for the rows grouped I want to sum the decimal values. I know how to do the sum part, but how do you group two different columns in a datatable?

This is my code so far which doesn't work properly:

```
var newSort = from row in objectTable.AsEnumerable()
              group row by new {ID = row.Field<string>("resource_name"), time1 = row.Field<DateTime>("day_date")} into grp
              orderby grp.Key
              select new
              {
                 resource_name1 = grp.Key.ID,
                 day_date1 = grp.Key.time1,
                 Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<Decimal>("actual_hrs"))
              };
```

Comment: "The compiler thinks all the objects are the same, so every row is grouped"--Do you mean all the objects get put into one big group, so you end up with only one item in the `newSort` collection?

Comment: yes, newSort only contains the last element of the datatable

Comment: The query looks correct to me. Can you check and re-check your inputs?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think you're giving us the full story. Other than `orderby` not working with anonymous types (the code you gave wouldn't have compiled), your query should work the way you want. I just put this in LINQPad:

```
var objectTable = new DataTable();
objectTable.Columns.Add("resource_name",typeof(string));
objectTable.Columns.Add("day_date",typeof(DateTime));
objectTable.Columns.Add("actual_hrs",typeof(decimal));
objectTable.Rows.Add(1, DateTime.Today, 1);
objectTable.Rows.Add(2, DateTime.Today, 2);

var newSort = from row in objectTable.AsEnumerable()
            group row by new {ID = row.Field<string>("resource_name"), time1 = row.Field<DateTime>("day_date")} into grp
            select new
                {
                    resource_name1 = grp.Key.ID,
                    day_date1 = grp.Key.time1,
                    Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<Decimal>("actual_hrs"))
                };
newSort.Dump();
```

... and I got these results:

```
resource_name1 | day_date1            | Sum
1              | 7/1/2011 12:00:00 AM | 1 
2              | 7/1/2011 12:00:00 AM | 2
```

Comment: Curious to know how can I pull one row from each group from the above based on the MIN value of two other columns combined?

Comment: @Si8: `grp.OrderBy(g => g.col1 + g.col2).FirstOrDefault()`?

Answer (score 4):

use this code

```
var newSort = from row in objectTable.AsEnumerable()
          group row by new {ID = row.Field<string>("resource_name"), time1 =    row.Field<DateTime>("day_date")} into grp
          orderby grp.Key
          select new
          {
             resource_name1 = grp.Key.ID,
             day_date1 = grp.Key.time1,
             Sum = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.ItemArray[2]))
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that want a solution in Vb.net, here is an example:

```
Dim workTable As DataTable = New DataTable("Customers")

Dim workCol As DataColumn = workTable.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
workTable.Columns.Add("Total", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
workTable.Columns.Add("Compra", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))

Dim row As DataRow = workTable.NewRow()
row("id") = 2
row("total") = 1.5
row("compra") = 3
workTable.Rows.Add(row)
row = workTable.NewRow()

row("id") = 1
row("total") = 1.5
row("compra") = 3.3999999999999999
workTable.Rows.Add(row)
row = workTable.NewRow()
row("id") = 1
row("total") = 1.5
row("compra") = 5
workTable.Rows.Add(row)


Dim detalles As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = workTable.AsEnumerable()

Dim query = From detalle In detalles.AsEnumerable() _
            Group detalle By grupoClave = New With _
                                        { _
                                            Key .C2 = detalle("id"), _
                                            Key .C4 = detalle("total")} Into g = Group _
                                    Select New With _
                                    { _
                                        .Col2 = g(0).Field(Of Integer)("id"), _
                                        .Col3 = g(0).Field(Of Decimal)("total"), _
                                        .Col4 = g.Sum(Function(fact) fact.Field(Of Decimal)("compra")) _
                                    }

For Each p In query
    Console.WriteLine((p.Col2 & p.Col3 & p.Col4))
Next
```