# Calculating percentage of a groups from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a `datatable` that looks like below

[image]
My result Should be  A=40%  , B=60% .. ie 2/5 and 3/5
Group name can be A, B, C, etc...

How can i calculate the figures based on that datatable values??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LINQ and cast it to a dictionary:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("test1");
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("TASKID"), new DataColumn("GROUPID"), new DataColumn("GROUPNAME") });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, 2, "A" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, 3, "B" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, 2, "A" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 14, 3, null });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 15, 3, "B" });
var query = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
                group row by row["GROUPNAME"] into g
                select g).ToDictionary(x => (x.Key.ToString() == "" ? "*" : x.Key.ToString()), x => (int)((x.Count() * 100) / dt.Rows.Count));
```

Iterate through the dictionary to display the values:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int> kvp in query)
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " - " + kvp.Value.ToString());
```

The output:

```
A - 40
B - 40
* - 20
```

The percentage is cast as an int.  simply change `(int)((x.Count() * 100) / dt.Rows.Count)` if you need more accurate values.

Comment: thanks @tinstaafi.. but how can i check nullvalue for the x.Key

Comment: @SRJ The nullvalue should appear as an empty key.  If you want a visible value for it , you can use an inline conditional statement. I added some code to show how to replace the value with a "*".

Comment: @tinstaafi . Thanks. Can i group by multiople filelds. eg: here i want to grouup by GROUPNAME and USERID

Comment: It should be possible but you might need a better data sample and expected output sample to make sure you get a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way, through loop. The following should be similar to the one you require.

```
//Simulated datatable
DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
table1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TaskID", typeof(int)));
table1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GroupID", typeof(int)));
table1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GroupName", typeof(String)));

//Entered test values
DataRow dr1 = null;

dr1 = table1.NewRow();
dr1["TaskID"] = 12;
dr1["GroupID"] = 2;
dr1["GroupName"] = "A";

table1.Rows.Add(dr1);

dr1 = table1.NewRow();
dr1["TaskID"] = 13;
dr1["GroupID"] = 3;
dr1["GroupName"] = "B";

table1.Rows.Add(dr1);

dr1 = table1.NewRow();
dr1["TaskID"] = 14;
dr1["GroupID"] = 2;
dr1["GroupName"] = "A";

table1.Rows.Add(dr1);

dr1 = table1.NewRow();
dr1["TaskID"] = 15;
dr1["GroupID"] = 3;
dr1["GroupName"] = "B";

table1.Rows.Add(dr1);

dr1 = table1.NewRow();
dr1["TaskID"] = 16;
dr1["GroupID"] = 3;
dr1["GroupName"] = "B";

table1.Rows.Add(dr1);

//solution starts from here
Dictionary<string, int> totalCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < table1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (totalCount.Keys.Contains(table1.Rows[i]["GroupName"].ToString()))
    {
        int currVal = totalCount[table1.Rows[i]["GroupName"].ToString()];
        totalCount[table1.Rows[i]["GroupName"].ToString()] = currVal + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        totalCount[table1.Rows[i]["GroupName"].ToString()] = 1;
    }
}

foreach (var item in totalCount)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.Value.ToString());
}
```

OR

```
//solution starts from here
var data = table1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(m => m.Field<string>("GroupName")).Select(grp => new
{
    GroupName = grp.Key,
    Count = (int)grp.Count()
}).ToList();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the groupname can be A,B , ...etc. any thing.. which may repeat any no of times.

Comment: Yes, give me a minute.

Comment: Can i group by multiople filelds. eg: here i want to grouup by GROUPNAME and USERID

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible. You need to use the `new` keyword inside `GroupBy` method and then you can include multiple columns. Check the example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551447/c-using-linq-to-group-by-multiple-columns-in-a-datatable)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751478/how-to-show-dynamically-generated-datatable-in-reportviewer-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq

```
   var data=datatable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(m => m.Field<string>("GROUPNAME")).Select(grp => new
                    {
                        GROUPNAME= grp.Key,
                        Count = (int)grp.Count()
                    });
```