# How to show dynamically generated datatable in reportviewer in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, reportviewer, rdlc

I've a `ReportViewer(.rdlc)` in my app. I want to show a `datatable`, which is generated dynamically from codebehind, in Reportviewer in Table object.

How to do this?  dataset has to be sent to report through codebehind.

I Have My Code Behind file

```
  DataTable dt = Session["ReportOnUser"] as DataTable;
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
      ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("ReportOnUser", dt);
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
  }
```

**aspx file**:

```
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="800px">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\Report1.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ReportOnUser" Name="ReportOnUser" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I have adde an rdlc file with No design or xsd file  Report1.rdlc.

Comment: Are you getting an error? You got the idea right, you need to set the report's data source, and that should be it...

Comment: am not geting error. but report is generated with no rows.

Comment: Do you have a tablix on your report to actually show the data?

Comment: No. I have onle added a blank .rdlc , and this not win forms but asp.net

Comment: You need to add a data source in your report, and bind a table to that data source. The data source name should be "ReportOnUser". If you use the wizard for a new report you should be able to pick a datasource from different sources, I usually go with Object data source and have a c# class acting as a model

Comment: But when ading a datasourse i am getting compatiablty error as am using sqlserver 2012 and VS 2008. But i jst added an xsd with a datatable with  samename of dt.. not working. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54007/discussion-between-srj-and-andrei-d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code above is working perfectly. the only issue was 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms' dll added was of different version.