# GroupBy Datatable with multiple column values

Tags: vb.net, linq, uipath

I have to group by PatientMedicareNumber, startdateofservice and enddateofservice.

Input is like this: [image: Input]

I have groupby only using patientmedicarenumber which is working fine. However, if I want to include startdate and enddate the logic is not working as expected and showing null error.

```
in_dt_WPSFileInput.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(r) New With{Key.Supplier = r("PatientMedicareNumber")}).[Select](Function(g) g.OrderBy(Function(r) r("PatientMedicareNumber")).First()).CopyToDataTable()
```

I want to have 7 groupby which have to generate result as 7 datatable as follows [image: output]

Found some queries online and using this but this result same as the input -

```
(From d In in_dt_WPSFileInput
Group d By a1=d("PatientMedicareNumber").tostring.trim,a2=d("DateofServiceStart").tostring.trim,a3=d("DateofServiceEnd").tostring.trim Into grp=Group
Where grp.count>=1
Select grp.tolist).SelectMany(Function(x) x).copytodatatable()
```

How to groupby using multiple columns with same value match?

Comment: like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551447/c-using-linq-to-group-by-multiple-columns-in-a-datatable) ?

Comment: Well, if there are null values, you get an NRE when calling `.tostring.trim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that you want 7 datatables instead of one then you can use the below LINQ:

```
(From d In in_dt_WPSFileInput
Group d By a1=d("PatientMedicareNumber").tostring,a2=d("DateofServiceStart").tostring,a3=d("DateofServiceEnd").tostring Into grp=Group
Select grp.CopyToDataTable).ToArray
```

Output of this LINQ will be array of datatable. In your case it will array containing 7 datatables.